# Transpose dataframe in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, transpose

I have a dataframe like this

**Input**

```
>>> df

 sent      cite 
 a         1,2,3
 b         2,4
 c         5
```

I want to transpose the dataframe that each row contains the values of cite and sent combined. Notice that the `cite` and the `sent` can be repeated (e.g, `cite 2`)

**Expected Output**

```
>>> df

 cite      sent 
 1         a
 2         a
 2         b
 3         a
 4         b
 5         c
```

I have tried with this but it did not work

```
df = df.pivot( columns='cite', values='sent')
```

Comment: what is the dtype that is holding the values in the DataFrame? list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `split` then `explode`

```
df = df.assign(cite=df['cite'].str.split(',')).explode('cite')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`df.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
In [141]: df = df.assign(cite=df['cite'].str.split(',')).explode('cite').sort_values('cite')

In [142]: df
Out[142]: 
  sent cite
0    a    1
0    a    2
1    b    2
0    a    3
1    b    4
2    c    5
```